# Un/centering an interaction term whose slope is random

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, glmm

I am trying to fit a GLMM using the lme4 package. As my dataset is confidential I will attempt to explain it using an analogy.

I have 21 solar panels from different manufacturers (Panel_ID). Each solar panel is comprised of thousands of individual cells. Each cell has a baseline efficiency rating (Base_ER) that is positive and continuous. The panels are exposed to sunlight for a large amount of time, and the cumulative amount of energy deposited in each cell is recorded (Exposure), which is also a positive continuous variable. At a later time point, the new efficiency rating (Post_ER) is measured again in order to see how much degradation has occurred. This is the outcome we are trying to model.

Upon examining the data, an interaction effect is observed between Base_ER and Exposure. Base_ER moderates the rate of degradation caused by Exposure (steeper slopes for larger Base_ER values). See figure below for data of the cells from Panel #1.

[image: Cells from Panel 1]

Panels #2-21 all show the same downward trend too but with different intercepts and slopes/decay rates.

From a theoretical standpoint, allowing the slope for Exposure to vary for each manufacturer (Panel_ID) makes sense, as some are more sensitive than others. By extension, the slope of the interaction term (Base_ER:Exposure) should also be allowed to vary since fixing this makes little sense when the slope of Exposure is allowed to vary.

And so we arrive at the current formulation-

`m1 = glmer(Post_ER ~ Base_ER + Exposure + Base_ER:Exposure + (Exposure + Base_ER:Exposure|Panel_ID), data, family = gaussian(link = "log"))`

When I first ran this analysis, I mean centered Base_ER and Exposure. Here's the summary of what I got.

```
 Family: gaussian  ( log )
Formula: Post_ER ~ Base_ER_C + Exposure_C + Base_ER_C:Exposure_C + (Exposure_C + Base_ER_C:Exposure_C | Panel_ID)
   Data: data
Control: control

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 244855.3  244953.9 -122416.7  244833.3     57475 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.0239 -0.5942 -0.0630  0.5073  9.8089 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                 Variance  Std.Dev. Corr       
 Panel_ID (Intercept)          1.799e-01 0.424156            
          Exposure_C           1.228e-04 0.011082  0.43      
          Exposure_C:Base_ER_C 2.664e-06 0.001632 -0.26 -0.23
 Residual                      4.107e+00 2.026460            
Number of obs: 57486, groups:  Panel_ID, 21

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           1.8177102  0.0456964  39.778   <2e-16 ***
Base_ER_C             0.0731007  0.0003751 194.859   <2e-16 ***
Exposure_C           -0.0184618  0.0011960 -15.437   <2e-16 ***
Base_ER_C:Exposure_C -0.0002858  0.0001768  -1.616    0.106    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Bs_ER_C Exps_C
Base_ER_C   -0.015               
Exposure_C   0.428 -0.011        
Bs_ER_C:E_C -0.259  0.078  -0.233
optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK)
```

I then ran the analysis with the terms uncentered and got a very different coefficient for the interaction term, which even flipped signs and became statistically significant. Here's the summary for that-

```
 Family: gaussian  ( log )
Formula: Post_ER ~ Base_ER + Exposure + Base_ER:Exposure + (Exposure + Base_ER:Exposure | Panel_ID)
   Data: data
Control: control

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 244431.9  244530.4 -122204.9  244409.9     57475 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.9894 -0.5871 -0.0579  0.5018  9.9041 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name             Variance  Std.Dev. Corr       
 Panel_ID (Intercept)      1.531e-01 0.391314            
          Exposure         2.125e-04 0.014579 -0.39      
          Exposure:Base_ER 4.412e-06 0.002101  0.04 -0.71
 Residual                  4.076e+00 2.018934            
Number of obs: 57486, groups:  Panel_ID, 21

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       1.5359978  0.0424768  36.161   <2e-16 ***
Base_ER           0.0679425  0.0002964 229.245   <2e-16 ***
Exposure         -0.0205527  0.0015903 -12.924   <2e-16 ***
Base_ER:Exposure  0.0005394  0.0002278   2.368   0.0179 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Bas_ER Exposr
Base_ER     -0.087              
Exposure    -0.390  0.096       
Bs_ER:Expsr  0.042 -0.057 -0.708
optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK)
```

I know that when you center the main variables involved in an interaction their coefficients change, but the coefficient of their interaction term is the same. However, this was not the case when I chose to allow the coefficient of the interaction term to vary. **Why does this happen?** Is one model *more correct* than the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I know that when you center the main variables involved in an interaction their coefficients change, **but the coefficient of their interaction term is the same.**"  What makes you say that ?

Comment: Isn't that normally how it is? See [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/05/regression-with-interaction-terms-how-centering-predictors-influences-main-effects/).

I also see it in my data if I remove the interaction term from being a random slope. If I then run the model centered or uncentered, the interaction coefficient is the same. This is not the case when I have it as a random slope however. Centering or uncentering has a large impact on the coefficient of the interaction term, as seen in the main post.

Comment: For another source see [here](https://www.bauer.uh.edu/jhess/papers/JMRMeanCenterPaper.pdf), page 9 second paragraph.

Comment: Let's make sure we are on the same page. Try this code: `N <- 100; X1 <- runif(N, 1, 5) ; X2 <- runif(N, 1, 5); Y <- X1 + X2 + X1*X2 + rnorm(N); 
lm(Y ~ X1*X2); X3 <- scale(X2); lm(Y ~ X1*X3)`.
After centering, all the estimates change, as expected (by me at least), though I guess you must be talking about something else ?

Comment: Where we differ is how we center and what we center. I am centering *both* variables involved in the interaction. X1 and X2. Also, I do not standardise (divide by sd). I only mean deviate. This will result in identical coefficients for the interaction term but different coefficients for the main effects.

Here's the code for what I mean: `N <- 100; X1 <- runif(N, 1, 5) ; X2 <- runif(N, 1, 5); Y <- X1 + X2 + X1*X2 + rnorm(N);  lm(Y ~ X1*X2); X3 <- scale(X2, TRUE, FALSE);  X4 <- scale(X1, TRUE, FALSE); lm(Y ~ X4*X3)`

Comment: @RobertLong Hope the the issue I am facing is more apparent now. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, I can see the issue, but I haven't been able to get my head around it yet. Some simulations/testing are needed I think and I don't have too much time right now. The interaction estimate is a couple orders magnitude smaller than the next largest estimate and completely trivial compare to the intercept. Is the problem any different when you use `lmer` ?

Comment: It is indeed magnitudes smaller but because it's a multiplicative interaction term, it can still have a comparable effect right? (eg. if the two independent variables are at a large value). Yes the same thing seems to happen with lmer too.